# Recurring payments paypal IPN

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am working on client's project for paid memberships.

clients want to do recurring payments and i am stumped upon IPN settings for recurring payments.

As Paypal say, if notify_url is specified in html form it  will override Paypal's default notify_url if specified. That's fine for one time payment.

But what for recuring payments ? which Settings paypal use for sending IPN notifications to clients server. Is that the notify url which user specified for first time in HTML form or Paypal's default ipn settings ?

what if user hasnot specified paypal default ipn setting ? but had specified it in html form when user was  subscribing for the  first time.

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I have is that notify_url only works for the initial transaction but for the recurring payment, IPN url is being used.

I am also trying to get some answers to verify if this is how it works as there are people with different opinion and offical doc doesn't seem to have this info in detail.

Comment: what do you mean IPN url? In the classic paypal solution I have, then notify_url that I set is the IPN endpoint. I do not have anywhere else where to set the IPN url. I want to implement IPN with the rest API, but I dont know where to set the IPN endpoint.